# Queen Contiquity has / exceed unshared borders (R)

Tags: r

Hi everyone (first Question ever in Stackflow),

my Queen Contiquity seems to like Slovakia even though she's in Balearen (spain).

Data used: NUTS2

Could someone help me?

Thanks alot!

```
queen_nb <- poly2nb(shp_eu, row.names = shp_eu@data$NUTS_I, queen = T)  #creates a neighborhood list

W.list.queen <- nb2listw(queen_nb, style = "W", zero.policy = TRUE) #creates a weights-list

W.queen <- listw2mat(W.list.queen) #creates a weights matrix

plot(shp_eu)
plot(queen_nb, coords, lwd=.2, col="red", cex = .5, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Please identify the packages you are using, together with a description of the problem appropriate to those not familiar with your area.  I'm not ashamed to admit I have no idea what a "queen contiquity" is...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

vielleicht hilft das an dieser Stelle weiter:

translated: "Maybe this will help you:"

Bei uns lag der entscheidende Knackpunkt darin, die Koordinatenmatrix erst NACH dem Sortieren des shape files zu erstellen, statt - wie im Skript - davor.

translated: "It's important to create the coordinate matrix **after** you sort the shapefile."

```
shp_eu <- readOGR("./shape_nuts2/shape_nuts2.shp")
shp_eu <- shp_eu[order(shp_eu@data$NUTS_I),] # order shape file

coords <-coordinates(shp_eu) # creates a matrix with the coordinates for all regions
```

Auf diese Weise stimmen finally sowohl die Nachbarregionen der Queen contiguity Matrix (stimmten auch davor) als auch jene der k-nearest Matrix (stimmt erst jetzt) mit den tatsächlichen Regionen überein.

translated: "This way the regional neighbors of the matrix and the KNN results match."